# X has 14 features, but RandomForestClassifier is expecting 20 features as input

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

Could I please ask, I have this code (a reproducible example):

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV 
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold,KFold
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest 
#from xgboost import XGBClassifier 
from sklearn.feature_selection import mutual_info_classif 
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, RFECV 
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline 
from sklearn.svm import SVC 
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier 
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB 
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression 
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer, recall_score, accuracy_score, precision_score 
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold 
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer 
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score,recall_score,f1_score,roc_auc_score 
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from numpy import mean 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from numpy import std 
from sklearn.utils import shuffle 
import numpy as np 
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pickle
#import neptune.new as neptune
import pandas as pd
import shap

full_X_train,full_y_train = make_classification(n_samples =500,n_features = 20, random_state=1, n_informative=10,n_redundant=10)


def run_model_with_grid_search(param_grid={}, output_plt_file = 'plt.png',model_name=RandomForestClassifier(),X_train=full_X_train,y_train=full_y_train,model_id='random_forest_with_hpo_no_fs_geno_class', n_splits=5, output_file='random_forest_with_hpo_no_fs_geno_class.txt'): 


      cv_outer = KFold(n_splits=5,shuffle=True,random_state=1)
      acc_list = list()
      f1_list = list()
      precision_list = list()
      recall_list = list()
      auc_list = list()


      #for ROC curve
      tprs = []
      base_fpr = np.linspace(0, 1, 101)
      plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
      plt.axes().set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')
      count = 0

      list_shap_values = list()
      list_test_sets = list()

      for train_ix,test_ix in cv_outer.split(X_train):
              split_x_train, split_x_test = X_train[train_ix,:],X_train[test_ix,:] #add in .iloc               
              split_y_train, split_y_test = y_train[train_ix],y_train[test_ix]  #add in .iloc

              cv_inner = KFold(n_splits=3,shuffle=True,random_state=1)
              model = model_name
              rfecv = RFECV(estimator=model, step=1,scoring='accuracy',cv=cv_inner) #change scoring to scoring='roc_auc'
              pipeline = Pipeline([('feature_sele',rfecv),('clf_cv',model)])
              search = GridSearchCV(pipeline,param_grid=param_grid,scoring='roc_auc',cv=cv_inner,refit=True).fit(split_x_train,split_y_train)
              best_model = search.best_estimator_
              best_model_shap = search.best_estimator_['clf_cv'].fit(split_x_train,split_y_train)
              print(search.best_params_)
              
              
              yhat = best_model.predict(split_x_test)  #changed from best_model and split_x_test

              accuracy = accuracy_score(split_y_test,yhat)
              acc_list.append(accuracy)

              f1_sc = f1_score(split_y_test,yhat)
              f1_list.append(f1_sc)

              precision_sc = precision_score(split_y_test,yhat)
              precision_list.append(precision_sc)

              recall_sc = recall_score(split_y_test,yhat)
              recall_list.append(recall_sc)
              
              fpr, tpr, _ = roc_curve(split_y_test, yhat)
              auc = metrics.auc(fpr,tpr)
              auc_list.append(auc)

              plt.plot(fpr, tpr, 'b', alpha=0.15)
              tpr = np.interp(base_fpr, fpr, tpr)
              tpr[0] = 0.0
              tprs.append(tpr)
              count +=1

              print('>acc=%.3f,est=%.3f,cfg=%s'%(accuracy,search.best_score_,search.best_params_))

              explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(best_model_shap)
              shap_values = explainer.shap_values(split_x_test)
              list_shap_values.append(shap_values)
              list_test_sets.append(test_ix) 

      test_set = list_test_sets[0]
      shap_values = np.array(list_shap_values[0])

      for i in range(1,len(list_test_sets)):
          test_set = np.concatenate((test_set,list_test_sets[i]),axis=0)
          shap_values = np.concatenate((shap_values,np.array(list_shap_values[i])),axis=1)


      X_test_df = pd.DataFrame(full_X_train[test_set])
      cols = X_test_df.columns
      shap_sum = np.abs(shap_values[1,:,:]).mean(0)
      

      importance_df = pd.DataFrame({
           'column_name':cols,
           'shap_values':shap_sum
      }) 
           
      importance_df.sort_values('shap_values',ascending=False)

      print('Accuracy: %.3f (%.3f)' % (mean(acc_list),std(acc_list)))
      print('F1: %.3f (%.3f)' % (mean(f1_list),std(f1_list)))
      print('Precision: %.3f (%.3f)' % (mean(precision_list),std(precision_list)))
      print('Recall: %.3f (%.3f)' % (mean(recall_list),std(recall_list)))
      print('AUC: %.3f (%.3f)' % (mean(auc_list),std(auc_list)))


      tprs = np.array(tprs)
      mean_tprs = tprs.mean(axis=0)
      tpr_std = tprs.std(axis=0)

      tprs_upper = np.minimum(mean_tprs + tpr_std, 1)
      tprs_lower = mean_tprs - tpr_std


      plt.plot(base_fpr, mean_tprs, 'b')
      plt.fill_between(base_fpr, tprs_lower, tprs_upper, color='grey', alpha=0.3)
      plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1],'r--')
      plt.xlim([-0.01, 1.01])
      plt.ylim([-0.01, 1.01])
      plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
      plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
      plt.title('ROC for stratified 5-fold CV (blue line = mean)')
      plt.savefig(output_plt_file)

      print(importance_df)

      return


param_grid = [{
               'clf_cv__min_samples_leaf':[1,3,5],
[200,500,700,1000,1500,2000]
              }]

run_model_with_grid_search(param_grid=param_grid)
```

I get the error:

```
X has 14 features, but RandomForestClassifier is expecting 20 features as input
```

I can see other people have had this issue understand the problem (I think) - it's because I do feature selection before I build a model, but then I don't transform my X test data to be the same dimensions.

I was trying to implement solutions based on seeing other people's work e.g.

```
              search = GridSearchCV(pipeline,param_grid=param_grid,scoring='roc_auc',cv=cv_inner,refit=True).fit(split_x_train,split_y_train)
              best_model = search.best_estimator_
              best_model_shap = search.best_estimator_['clf_cv'].fit_transform(split_x_train,split_y_train)
              print(search.best_params_)
              
              transformed_x_test = best_model.transform(split_x_test)
              yhat = best_model.predict(transformed_x_test)  #changed from best_model and split_x_test
```

But that is leading to other errors (e.g. in this case, 'GridSerchCV object has no attribute fit_transform') - so I'm just not clear how to implement other's solutions to my issue.

Could someone please demonstrate to me how to get this piece of code working (it should all work except for this error anyway). Also, if someone could show me how to print which features are being selected by the feature selection process that would be great but I think I can figure that out after this starts working.